# Php mySQL prepare a sequel and only show results linked to the userId of who is logged in

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
<?php
require_once 'connection.php';

$p_sql = "SELECT *
    FROM pq_posts p
    JOIN pq_users u ON p.userId = u.userId
    JOIN pq_user_profiles up ON p.userId = up.userId
    WHERE userId = :userId
    ORDER BY timestamp DESC ";

$stmt = $dbConn -> prepare($p_sql);
$stmt->execute( array (":userId" => $_SESSION['userName']));
$posts = $stmt->fetchAll();
?>
```

**NOTE:**
I want to display results from the database, only where the posts (pq_posts) are coming from users currently logged in with a 'userId'. This is because I am creating a page for 'Admin Home'...

**I get this error:**

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'userId' in where clause is ambiguous' in /home/CLASSES/natovmatiej/CST336/final_project/admin_postquotes.php:50 Stack trace: #0 /home/CLASSES/natovmatiej/CST336/final_project/admin_postquotes.php(50): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in /home/CLASSES/natovmatiej/CST336/final_project/admin_postquotes.php on line 50

**Line 50:**

```
$stmt->execute( array (":userId" => $_SESSION['userName']));
```

Thank you.

Comment: the most significant part of the emperor is this " 'userId' in where clause is ambiguous'" when doing a join you probably have the same name (userId) in the other tables

Comment: ambiguous userid.. this means you're to specify on which table the userId belongs to... i think it must be u.userId

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is that in `WHERE` clause you write `userId`, but you should specify the table like `p.userId` or `u.userId` :

```
$p_sql = "SELECT
          FROM pq_posts p
          JOIN pq_users u ON p.userId = u.userId
          JOIN pq_user_profiles up ON p.userId = up.userId
          WHERE p.userId = :userId
          ORDER BY timestamp DESC ";
```